# mov or m4v video embedding (data retrieved from mysql database via php)

Tags: html, video, embed

I am designing a site for an ad production company that want to be able to upload location scouting and casting videos. I have figured out how to get the data out of sql and into the browser with proper headers.

Now my issue is - what is the best way to display video at present. I need it to work on iPhones, iPads, Safari and Firefox. I don't care about IE at all.

I don't mind restricting them to uploading in only one video format if that helps. Meaning Quicktime .mov only or .m4v only - whatever works. Can't use Flash as iPhones and iPads are involved.

I also have no issue accommodating each different browser with different code. I just need to know which method is best for which platform/browser.

EDIT:

I have figured out how to display the video from the database in the computer browsers I care about (excludes MSIE). Now I need to figure out the iPhone. To test, I put the files into the server's files system and they all play from there via the html5 video tag. So the iPhone is capable of playing the clips' formats. The issue is apparently passing that data to the iPhone from mySQL... Currently, my php file that retrieves the binary data and sends it to the browser specifies the following headers:

```
header("Content-length: $audioLength");  
header('Content-Range: bytes 0-'.$audioLength.'/'.$audioLength);  
header("Content-type: ".$mimeType);
```

where $audioLength is the file size in bytes captured on upload
$mimeType is the mime type as reported by the browser at upload - both values are passed to the retrieve_audio.php script form the database along with the binary data.

What other headers may be necessary? How would I find out what the difference is between getting the file from the filesystem versus the database?

Is is possible the issue is that the iPhone doesn't retrieve the data until you press the play button? As a last resort, I could have the PHP code write the file(s) to the filesystem, but that is duplication of data that I would like to avoid, if possible...

Thanks,

M

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/video.html for great info on HTML5 video and different formats.

Simplified short answer: Firefox 4 supports Ogg (Theora/Vorbis) and WebM; Safari (desktop and mobile) supports MP4 (H.264/AAC). Try using the HTML5 `<video>` tag like this:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="pr6.mp4"  type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
    <source src="pr6.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
    <source src="pr6.ogv"  type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
</video>
```

(Example from site linked above. Seriously, it's a really good read, and it will also tell you how to make sure your video *does* work in IE, Chrome, etc.)

**EDIT** If you absolutely need to only use one video format, your best bet is probably MP4/M4V with H.264 video and AAC audio. Safari (desktop and mobile) can play it in the `<video>` tag, and Firefox will be able to play it in a Flash container. It's not ideal, because I think you'll have to do some browser sniffing to make sure iOS doesn't get Flash and Firefox does, but you'll want something like this:

```
<!-- Safari and iOS -->
<video width="320" height="240" poster="poster.jpg" controls>
    <source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
</video>

<!-- Firefox / other -->
<object width="320" height="240" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
    <param value="player.swf">
    <param value="true" name="allowfullscreen">
    <param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess">
    <param value="file=video.mp4&amp;image=poster.jpg" name="flashvars">
    <embed
        width="320"
        height="240"
        flashvars="file=video.mp4&amp;image=poster.jpg"
        allowfullscreen="true"
        allowscriptaccess="always"
        src="player.swf"
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    >
</object>
```

Even if you go this route, though, I'd still read the Dive Into HTML5 page for more info about the appropriate codecs to use, how to encode the video, and various problems to look out for.

Comment: OK - that's with the html5 video tag. I know for sure that there are ways to embed the same clip into the browsers that I am interested in because the sample the client showed me was an iWeb generated page. I will try to reverse engineer that. I don't care about being on the cutting edge - I just want it to work without having to use different video formats.

Comment: With one video format, you'll probably want to go with H.264 in MP4/M4V, and put it in a Flash container for Firefox. Downside is you'll need to do browser-sniffing. I edited my answer with info about this.

Comment: Actually, Firefox doesn't appear to have an issue playing back .mov and .m4v files via the <object> tag... I am only having an issue playing back on the iPhone when the data is retrieved from the database as opposed to the server's filesystem. Please see my edits to the original post...

Comment: I would not store the video data in the database in the first place.  Only put metadata about the video into the database and store the actual video data on the filesystem.  That way Apache can use all of it's fancy tricks to stream the data efficiently as well as handle byte ranges etc.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no single format that works well on such a wide variety of devices.  You'll need to take whatever format is uploaded and convert it into a number of different formats.  You might want to look into a service like http://www.livetranscoding.com/ to do the heavy lifting (note, I've not used their services and I don't know if there's a way to get it to work with non-live streams).

Comment: Not willing to do that - (not me, the client). Apple's consumer level WYSIWYG app, iWeb, is able to to do this - from a first glimpse looks like they are generating different code based on some kind of browser detection - javascript generates tags that work for the three platforms I am interested in.